# iOS App without launch icon

Tags: ios, launcher, invisible

is there a way to unmark an app as "launcher app"?

In Andorid i can set a property in the manifest.xml "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER".
If the property isn't setted, a launcher icon is not visible after the installation.

background information:
I want to install (invisible) apps, which are always visbile in a certain app.

regards

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to do this on iOS.